# Results in a function python

Tags: python, loops

Why the print of this code is `3 3 3`? In the last `for` loop, the variable `D` should increase in 1 and then update the value, until the end of the loop. But it's repeating the same initial value of `D`. I was expecting something `3 4 5` as result.

```
for j in range(0,2,1):
    D = 1
    D +=1
"""D = 2"""

def calculo222(H):
    H += 1
    print(H)

for i in range(0,3,1):
    calculo222(D)
```

Comment: integers are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: Because you call the function three times with D and D is 2 in all three cases. Apart from that, you are initializing D=1 within the for-loop which makes no sense.

Comment: if you expect `3 4 5` as output then return the value of `H` in `calculo222()` function

Comment: I tried put `return H` in the end of `calculo222()` function and didn't work. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: but then you also need `D = calculo222(D)` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, arguments are passed by assignment, and ints are immutable, which means you can't modify an int that's passed in to a function. The easiest fix is to return it:

```
def calculo222(H):
    H += 1
    print(H)
    return H

D = 2
for _ in range(3):
    D = calculo222(D)
```

For more details, see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/4518341)